# Windows XP restarts itself suddenly

Tags: windows-xp, sp3, reboot

My computer (Windows XP sp3) gets stuck suddenly and restarts itself. When Windows loads I get the following message:

> **error Signature:**
>
> BCCode : 100000d1     BCP1 : 0000674B     BCP2 : 00000002     BCP3 : 00000000
>   BCP4 : BA9910DC     OSVer : 5_1_2600     SP : 3_0     Product : 256_1
>
> **error report content:**
>
> C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER811d.dir00\Mini090909-02.dmp
>
> C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER811d.dir00\sysdata.xml

Help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sonds like you aer getting a Blue Screen Of Death and you have the Reboot on Blue Screen option turned on. I would suggest updating all your drivers as a first step. You can also look at the dumop file (C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER811d.dir00\Mini090909-02.dmp) but erading those can be something of an esoteric art. I have heard of an app that will analyze a dump file for you but I don't remember the name off the top of my head. I'll see if I can find it.

So, the software that I was thinking of is [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed). I have not used it myself but I have heard other people mention that it is useful.

Comment: Thanks,
I ran a scan with 'WhoCrashed' - and got this message:

This was likely caused by the following module: gt72ubus.sys
Bugcheck code: 0x100000D1 (0x674B, 0x2, 0x0, 0xBA9910DC)
Error: Unknown
file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\gt72ubus.sys
company: Option N.V.

This is the driver of my USB Modem. (Icon 225)
I did not find an updated driver - I sent the company a Email, I hope they will help me...

Thank you all.

Comment: Good luck with that! USB modems are notoriously cheap and nasty, so crappy drivers that crash and aren't compatible with all OSes are, sadly, par for the course.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the DRIVER IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL bug
>   check. This indicates that a
>   kernel-mode driver attempted to access
>   pageable memory at a process IRQL that
>   was too high. This bug check is
>   usually caused by drivers that have
>   used improper addresses.
>
> Source: Debugging Tools for Windows

You need to use a bug check tool (see the other answer) to check which driver caused this problem, then you either find an update for that driver or you could disable the device if you don't need it.

If you upload the dump file (.dmp) we can try to look for you using a more advanced program.

Comment: In this case, it may not matter, but making an ambiguous reference to "see the other answer" is a bad habit due to the format of the stackoverflow, serverfault, and superuser sites. If more answers are added and votes aer applied there isn't any good way to know what answer is "the other answer". The more appropriate way to handle this issue on these sites would be for you to take my link to WhoCrashed and include it as an integral part of your answer. Attributing the other answerer is polite but not really required.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good thinking. I shall use the name of the other person instead then as I feel that integrating parts is like ripping their answer.